# Regex Expression, that picks value/values within inverted double quotes only

Tags: javascript, regex, django

I am trying to make a form validator using a javascript;

Value is itself a specific format it can be present 1 or more times, now when the value is tested I need to make sure if the value entered is enclosed within inverted double quotes.
Eg.

```
one value :- "C:GSMXXXX&T:GSMXXXX;"
```

more than one, here its 3..

```
"C:GSMXXXX&T:GSMXXXX; C:GSMXXXX&T:GSMXXXX; C:GSMXXXX&T:GSMXXXX;"
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried, where you got stuck, what is the expected output and what output you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex -

`"((C:GSM\d+&T:GSM\d+;(\s){0,}){1,})"`

Explanation-

1. inverted commas at the start and end are for the literal inverted commas in your expression
2. `C:GSM` and `T:GSM` are for the same literal strings
3. `\d+` means any number of numeric character
4. `(\s){0,}` means there can be 0 or more spaces at that location
5. `{1,}` means the whole expression can be matched more than one times

[Execution at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WLKCFq/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`"(.*?[^\\])"` 
[Here are all tested possibilities](https://regex101.com/r/Db4Ivq/1).

Comment: I have added up the regex for my value with your suggestion [here](https://regex101.com/r/Db4Ivq/3) but it still does not match...

Comment: Can you please update your question with the test string and expected output? Requirement is not clear to me as per the expression you have written.

Comment: link does not seems to be working so I  am wrting over here.. "(.*? **C:\sGSM[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\s\&\sT:\sGSM[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\s\;)** )"

Comment: [what is wrong in this expression?](https://regex101.com/r/Db4Ivq/6) why are you making it complicated?

Comment: I have to get values in form field only is specific order which is generated by clicking on a table cells. Thats why I want to restrict value entered into the form only to specific pattern. Thats why.